# Specifying object property in dot notation with a variable

Tags: python

Is it possible to access a property/method on a Python object with a variable and how?

Example:

```
handler.request.GET.add()
```

I'd like to replace the 'GET' part by capturing the method beforehand into a variable and then using it in the dot notation.

```
method = handler.method
handler.request.{method}.add()
```

I just can't see where/how to do that.

Comment: It's worth noting that often (not always, but often), when you think you need this, what you _really_ want is a `dict` mapping names to functions or methods. (This is easier to do in Python than many other languages, so it's appropriate much more often.)

Answer (score 27, accepted):

You are looking for `getattr`:

`getattr(handler.request, 'GET')` is the same as `handler.request.GET`.

So you can do

```
method = "GET"
getattr(handler.request, method).add()
```

Comment: Typo: should be `getattr(handler.request, method).add()`.

Answer (score 6):

Use the [`getattr()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr) to access dynamic attributes:

```
method = 'GET'
getattr(handler.request, method).add()
```

which would do exactly the same thing as `handler.request.GET.add()`.

Answer (score 2):

You could do something like [getattr](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#getattr)

```
getattr(handler.request, "GET").add()
```

Then just do

```
method = "GET" # or "POST"
getattr(handler.request, method).add()
```